# How do I remove garbage values from the backtracking algorithm?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Before I ask question, I am not good at English so it is hard to understand my word.

I've been trying to figure out how to solve Sudoku using the bit operator.
The first idea was to declare a three-dimensional array, add nine numbers that fit 9-9, and exclude the number of rows, columns and boxes corresponding to any coordinates.
However, I thought that using bit operators can reduce execution speed even more.

For example, if the number in one column of Sudoku is 1, I think it is a double square of 2.  This is equivalent to 0000 0000 0010.
Next, 4 shall be declared as 16, the fourth square of 2.
This is equivalent to 0000 0001 0000

Let's assume that all of the Sudoku that were first offered in this way were converted to binary system.
For example, if the first line is 1,2,5/0,8,4/9,3,7, if you use an 'or'(|) operator, the following might appear. 0011 1011 1110.
Using the 'not'(~) operator for this number will save the following number.
1100 0100 0001.
This shows that the number of zeros in the blank is six.

The problem is that there are more than one empty space, and in this case, I chose to enter the lower value and then move on to the next empty space.
And if you can't put it anymore, you can go back to the front using backtracking.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int map[9][9];  //2-Dimensional array to store Sudoku
int line[9];
int row[9];
int box[9];


int solve(int(*map)[9])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i<9; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            line[i] |= map[i][j];
            row[j] |= map[i][j];
            box[(j / 3) + 3 * (i / 3)] |= map[i][j];
        }
}

int solve1(int(*map)[9])
{
    short i = 0, j = 0;
    int num, num1, num2;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (map[i][j] == 0) //If the cell is empty
            {
                num = (~(line[i] | row[j] | box[(j / 3) + 3 * (i / 3)]));   //Use 'not' operator to find that number
                for (num1 = 1; num1 <= 9; num1++)
                {
                    num2 = 1<<num1;
                    if (num2&num)   //If and operator were used and not 0, it would be one of the numbers that could fit into the space.
                    {           printf("%d %d %d    ", i, j, num2);
                        map[i][j] = num2;
                        line[i] |= num2;
                        row[j] |= num2;
                        box[(j / 3) + 3 * (i / 3)] |= num2;
                        solve1(map);
                    }
                }
                return;     //backtracking
            }
        }
    }
    write(map);
}

int read(int(*map)[9])
{
    int i, j, k, num1;
    FILE*FP1 = fopen("data.txt", "r");  //Read the Sudoku saved in data.txt using the pointer.
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            fscanf(FP1, "%d", &map[i][j]);
            num1 = map[i][j];
            if (map[i][j] != 0)     
            {
                map[i][j] = 1;
                map[i][j] = map[i][j] << num1;  //Converts decimal to binary
            }
        }
    fclose(FP1);
}

int write(int(*map)[9])
{
    int i, j, idx;
    FILE*FP2 = fopen("result.txt", "a");
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            idx = 0;
            while (map[i][j] != 1)    //Converts binary to decimal
            {
                map[i][j] = map[i][j] >> 1;
                idx++;
            }
            fprintf(FP2, "%d ", idx);
        }
        fprintf(FP2, "\n");
    }
    fclose(FP2);
}

int main(void)
{
    read(map);
    solve(map);
    solve1(map);
    return 0;
}
```

However, there is no result when debug.
I already know that this is a problem.

```
line[i] |= num2;
row[j] |= num2;
box[(j / 3) + 3 * (i / 3)] |= num2;
```

When backtracking is performed, the number in the two-dimensional array is returned, but the use of the 'or' operator in the row / column /box is not returned, leaving the value of the trash.

If the above three array work together when I perform a backtracking, I can solve the problem.

Is there any way to solve this?

As I said earlier, You may not have been easy to see because I was not familiar with English, but thanks for reading it.

Comment: _I thought that using bit operators can reduce execution speed even more._ I guess you mean "reduce execution time" or "increase execution speed". (So, it's probably unnecessary to mention that bit operations are very likely among the fastest available operations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to *undo* the `|=` operations after the recursive call to `solve1` ?

You can set a specific bit to 0 in an `int` using bitwise and `&`:

```
int value; // value to modify
int bitIndex = 3; // Index of the bit to set to 0 (index starts from 0)

int mask = ~(1 << bitIndex); // All bits set to 1, except the one at bitIndex
value &= mask;
```

Note: if `value` is of a type `T` larger than int, `mask` should be defined as `T mask = ~((T)1 << bitIndex);`.

In your case, you almost have the mask:

```
line[i] |= num2; // set some bits to 1
line[i] &= ~num2; // set the same bits to 0
```

Comment: I understand what you mean.
I was also trying to remove 1 from the bit using the xor operator.
But I don't know where to put the code on the source.

Comment: @Kremlin You need to know if the recursive call to `solve1` was able to successfully fill the whole grid. Depending on this, you should either backtrack (return the solution you've just found), or undo the number you've just tried (to try something else).